# opencv cannot load the camera parameters (DynamicLib::libraryload ....\opencv_videoio_gstreamer452_64d.dll)

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, camera-calibration

When I run the code, the Calibration work but it cannot load the arucoMarker camera parameters in to the exe windows.
When I debug the code
The cmd get error DynamicLib::libraryload ....\opencv_videoio_gstreamer452_64d.dll every time it get into

```
vid.isOpened()
vid.read(frame)
```

Here is the full code of the function

```
void cameraCalibrationProcess(Mat& cameraMatrix, Mat& distortionCoefficients)
{
    Mat frame;
    Mat drawtoframe;
    vector<Mat> savedImages;
    vector<vector<Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates; //for aruco marker
    VideoCapture vid(0);
    if (!vid.isOpened())
    {
        return;
    }
    int framepersecond = 20;
    namedWindow("Webcam", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true)
    {
        if (!vid.read(frame))
            break;
        vector<Vec2f> foundpoints;
        bool found = false;
        found = findChessboardCorners(frame, checkerboard, foundpoints, CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE | CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);
        frame.copyTo(drawtoframe);
        drawChessboardCorners(drawtoframe, checkerboard, foundpoints, found);
        if (found)
        {
            imshow("Webcam", drawtoframe);
        }
        else
            imshow("Webcam", frame);
        char character = waitKey(1000 / framepersecond);

}
```

[image: Output windows]

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? I already see dead code there and without a `main()` it's hard to reproduce. Further, include the full error message and output you get. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sorry. I have shortened the code. And here is the main  https://pastebin.com/UpuPA0TJ

Comment: No. [edit] your question and include all relevant info. Also, don't use pictures to represent text, so that people (including yourself!) can easily search for e.g. error messages to find related questions.